# SocketChannel sockets not reading data

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Here is my code. From the TestServer, I'm trying to send data through an outputstream and have it received from the test client. I'm using a SocketChannel because I need the client to listen on 3 ports at the same time. At the moment, i'm only trying to read from one socket. However it doesnt seem to be receiving any data from the server. For the run method of KBThread, if I uncomment the nodata println, that will execute over and over.

TestServer.java

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TestServer extends JPanel implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private final int MAX_CLIENTS = 8;

    JPanel listenerPanel = new JPanel();
    JFrame listenerFrame = new JFrame();

    static DataOutputStream kbOut;
    static DataOutputStream mOut;
    static Socket dataSocket;

    public TestServer() {
        this.setFocusable(true);
        listenerPanel.addKeyListener(this);
        listenerPanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        listenerFrame.add(listenerPanel);
        listenerFrame.setSize(1376,808); // 10 more x, 40 more y.
        listenerFrame.setVisible(true);
        listenerFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        listenerPanel.requestFocusInWindow();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestServer().startServer();
    }

    public void startServer() {

        final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_CLIENTS);

        Runnable serverTask = () -> {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients.");
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error with client socket.");
            }
        };

        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
        serverThread.start();
    }

    private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                String clientIP = clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                System.out.println("Client connected from " + clientIP);

                Socket kbSocket = new Socket(clientIP, 1112);
                System.out.println("Keyboard socket connected to " + clientIP);
                kbOut = new DataOutputStream(kbSocket.getOutputStream());

                Socket mSocket = new Socket(clientIP, 1113);
                System.out.println("Mouse socket connected to " + clientIP);
                mOut = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());

                //new TestServer().startKBServer(clientIP);
                //new TestServer().startMServer(clientIP);

                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void startKBServer(String clientAddress) {

        Runnable kbTask = () -> {
            try {
                Socket kbSocket = new Socket(clientAddress, 1112);
                System.out.println("Keyboard socket connected to " + clientAddress);
                new KBTask(kbSocket);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error Calling Back " + clientAddress);
            }
        };

        Thread kbThread = new Thread(kbTask);
        kbThread.start();
    }

    private class KBTask implements Runnable {
        private final Socket kbSocket;

        private KBTask(Socket kbSocket) {
            this.kbSocket = kbSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                kbOut = new DataOutputStream(kbSocket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        try {
            int key = ke.getKeyCode();

            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + key);

            kbOut.writeInt(key);
            kbOut.flush();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing key data to server");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        try {
            int key = ke.getKeyCode();

            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + -key);

            kbOut.writeInt(-key);
            kbOut.flush();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing -key data to server");
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        try {
            int mouseX = me.getX();
            int mouseY = me.getY();

            if (mOut != null) {
                mOut.writeInt(mouseX);
                mOut.writeInt(mouseY);
                mOut.flush();
                System.out.println("Mouse Moved To: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
            }


        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing mouse data to server");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

    }
}
```

TestClient.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestClient {

    private final static String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.50";

    JPanel clientPanel = new JPanel();
    JFrame clientFrame = new JFrame();

    public void setupGUI() {

        clientFrame.add(clientPanel);
        clientFrame.setSize(200,200);
        clientFrame.setVisible(true);
        clientFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        clientPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            new TestClient().setupGUI();

            Robot keyRobot = new Robot();

            Socket firstSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, 1111);
            System.out.println("Connected to Commander. Address sent. Waiting for callback.");
            firstSocket.close();

            Selector selector = Selector.open();

            int ports[] = new int[] { 1112, 1113 };

            for (int port : ports) {
                ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
                serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            }

            while (true) {
                // After the 2 accept methods fire, it stops here and program doesnt continue.
                selector.select();
                Set setKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator selectedKeys = setKeys.iterator();


                while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey selectedKey = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                    if (selectedKey.isAcceptable()) {
                        SocketChannel socketChannel = ((ServerSocketChannel) selectedKey.channel()).accept();
                        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

                        switch (socketChannel.socket().getLocalPort()) {
                            case 1112:
                                System.out.println("Keyboard socket open.");
                                Runnable kbr = new KBThread(socketChannel.socket());
                                new Thread(kbr).start();
                                break;

                            case 1113:
                                System.out.println("Mouse socket open.");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    selectedKeys.remove();
                }


            }

            } catch (ConnectException ece) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to server: " + SERVER_IP);
        } catch (IOException | AWTException eio) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, eio);
        }
    }

    private static class KBThread implements Runnable {
        private final Socket kbSocket;
        private int dataID = 0;

        private KBThread(Socket kbSocket) {
            this.kbSocket = kbSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                DataInputStream kbDis = new DataInputStream(kbSocket.getInputStream());
                while (true) {
                    try {


                        if (kbDis.available() > 0) {
                            dataID = kbDis.readInt();
                            System.out.println(dataID);
                        }
                        //else System.out.println("noData");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how IO multiplexing is supposed to work.

Once a connection is accepted and marked non-blocking, add it to the same selector with `OP_READ`. Check for readable event in the loop, read from the socket. You don't need threads for this.

Alternatively, if you want to go with threads, don't set accepted client connection as non-blocking, just do regular reads from it in the dedicated thread.

#### Edit 0:

The best advise I can offer is to go over some good Java NIO tutorial. There many on the Intenet, but you can start here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/example/index.html
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html

Comment: Will this work for multiple clients connecting to the server? I need a client, which will connect at a random time, to connect to the server. This client gives the server his IP address. Then the client opens up 3 server sockets and the server connects to these 3 sockets. The server then sends data on each socket and the client reads the data from each socket.

Comment: It will work. You don't need to connect back to the client though - once client establishes a TCP connection it's a ***bi-directional stream of bytes***. Also in general the clients could be behind a NAT-ing firewall, and the server will not be able to connect back to them.

Comment: I tried adding OP_READ to the selector and I was getting illegal argument exceptions although I probably wasn't adding them in the right place. Can you explain your suggestion a bit more? It does make sense, I'm just not sure exactly how to implement. This application will only run on the local network and so firewalls are not a concern. I probably don't need threads, it just seemed like the only way to do this. I also used to have isReadable for the socket channel but it didn't work.

Comment: The other issue is that the client will keep running the code in isAcceptable and it tries to set configureBlocking again and hits a null pointer.

Comment: I was able to get it to send data by changing a few things. I had to keep selectedKeys.remove so that it would stop running the accept method first. However in my switch statement, I would add the selector back in with OP_READ as you suggested and now its working. Now i just need to figure out how to decode the bytebuffer into an int.

Comment: Another weird problem. Although I got it working, when I test both client and server on my computer, it sends the data properly (keycodes). However when I run the client on my laptop that is connected to the same network, when I hit a key on my PC, the laptop generates a buffer underflow exception. No idea why it works on one computer but not on the other.

Comment: So when the client is run on a separate computer, numBytesRead is returning 1 instead of 4 so of couse trying to readInt on that is generating an error. I have no idea why it's only reading 1 byte.

Comment: TCP connection is a *stream of bytes** - underlying OS stack can slice the bytes you send any way it wants. You have to deal with that.

Comment: I was going by that assumption, that it wasnt reading all of the bytes. I made multipel calls to socketchannel.read() and checked their size however it reports 1 byte and then 0 after that, so the rest of the bytes are not being sent. Is this a sender or receiver issue?

Comment: After that last comment, I did something else by adding a while loop and checking for buffer.remaining and now its working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep for comments so posting as answer. I am no expert but I believe you will have to use a PrintWriter on sockets output stream to pass the text back and forth. Here thisClient is a socket.

```
writer = new PrintWriter(thisClient.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("Transmitting");
writer.println(msg);
writer.flush();
```

Comment: I used dataoutputstreams when i was using regular IO instead of NIO. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I think yes.. Here is what I developed few months ago.. Its a basic chat/server client. Hope thi shelps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536934/java-multiple-thread-chat-server-sends-message-to-only-1-client

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work. I need multiple client connections and each client connects to multiple ports which is why I'm using NIO. dataoutputstreams worked completely fine with regular IO on sockets however sockets block on accept so I need to use NIO.